# Is it possible to Left outer join normal table with temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I create SQL server query and have normal table  with records  and in the other hand have a temp table with record and this table not empty  and all fields doesn't have any conflict to 
join

is possible to join this two different type table?

```
SELECT NormalTable.Entityname  FROM NormalTable LEFT JOIN 
       #Temp tmp ON tmp.joinID = NormalTable.joinID
```

Comment: yes ist is, which problem did you face?

Comment: thats return Invalid object name error

Comment: Show your data structure of both tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is possible to join this two different type table? (normal and temporary)

Yes it is possible to join different type of table (permanent and temporary tables). There is no different syntax to join these tables.

E.g.

Permanent table:

```
CREATE TABLE NormalTable
    ([plateno] varchar(1), [JoinID] int)
;

INSERT INTO NormalTable
    ([plateno], [JoinID])
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 2),
    ('C', 2),
    ('A', 3),
    ('B', 2),
    ('A', 4),
    ('A', 1)
;
```

Temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    ([id] int, [date] date, [score] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Temp
    ([id], [date], [score])
VALUES
    (1, '2013-04-13', 100),
    (2, '2013-04-14', 92),
    (3, '2013-04-15', 33)
;
```

Join both tables:

```
SELECT N.* FROM NormalTable N
LEFT JOIN #Temp T ON N.JoinID = T.ID
```

#### Have a look at [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f423f/5)