# In SQL, can you use JOIN with a temporary table?

Tags: sql

I have a query in which I first have a subquery where I define a temporary table.
(eg: I make a temporary table, youngcustomers, that only contains customers below a certain age)

Say I also have a table, allsales, that details every sale with columns: sale#, customername, product.
I want to join my youngcustomers table with my sales table on the customername column.  Is that possible?

(I hope this example is clear.  I also know that in this specific example I can get details about young customers easily but I'm asking for the general case)

Comment: Did you not just *try it*?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah that shouldn't be a problem. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759335/is-it-possible-to-left-outer-join-normal-table-with-temp-table), goes into more detail.